# Firebase on Spring Boot Default App

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, jhipster

I am creating a JHipster application (Springboot + Angular) and I need to integrate Firebase.

I've followed the instructions on firebase documentation and it works perfectly when I start the sever offline.

But when I deploy the server to AWS using `jhipster aws` in console, when I try to call a function that uses the firebase SDK it says `Trying to login to firebase failed. Reason: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!`

This behaviour happens only when I deploy the application because if I call it from a localhost it works perfectly.

I have this on my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-services</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I'm initializing my app using

```
try{
        InputStream serviceAccount = new ByteArrayInputStream(getFirebaseJson().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        //FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("firebaseAuth.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://seeu-soon.firebaseio.com/")
            .build();



        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance()).setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    }catch(Exception e){
        log.debug("Trying to login to firebase failed. Reason: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

Turns out that the `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);` function was executed once on the api when the environment was deployed to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

What I did was to create a class called FirebaseUtils which has a `initiateFirebase()` procedure, which sets the FirebaseApp.

Once I call the `initiateFirebase()` on each call of the API where I need access to firebase, the FirebaseApp is created with a new options configuration which is in another scope and I can access Firebase.

Comment: Did you manage to perform auth from the front end as well for example in React JS? How about login using Google or Facebook ? Would be great to have some samples on that