# Accessing files in the resource folder when the app is running on the server in a spring boot app

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I added Firebase auth to a spring boot project. For me to use the firebase resources, I have to add a json file that have the token for initialization  of  the firebase.  The code for the initialization looks like this.

```
try {


            InputStream serviceAccount =
                    PplusserverApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/xxxxxx.json");
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                    .build();


            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            FirebaseApp.getInstance().getName();
            logger.info("Is Firebase Started :"+FirebaseApp.getInstance().getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("stack: "+e.toString());
        }
```

It runs fine on the laptop and on tomcat locally. The problem comes when I deploy it to the sever. When I make a request to it I get this error "FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. ".

What I have tried:

1. I moved the json file to the static folder.

2)I added @EnableWebMvc to add the resources folder and have access to it.

3. I ran mvn generate resources when building the project.

Doing all this still gave me the same error "FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. "

I am deploying a war file on tomcat8 on aws ec2

How do I add the json file to the war and have access to it ? Or how would you solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I found post like mine that solved it. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976522/firebase-on-spring-boot-default-app

Answer (score 0):

It will help you to read from folder in spring boot application:

```
  Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:XXXX.json");
  InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

Also for resources  by autowiring `@Autowired ResourceLoader resourceLoader`

```
Resource resource = 
resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:XXXX.json");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

Comment: thanks. The problem is not accessing the file. The problem is that firebase is not initialize on the server.